# Все возможные комбинации одномерного массива

Tags: комбинаторика

Друзья подскажите в теории, какие бывают практики к подходу вычисления количества возможных комбинаций из элементов одномерного массива. И перебрать все возможные последовательности.

Например есть элементы 2,45,16,34 - как узнать возможные комбинации? ( не прошу кода, прошу теорию)

Comment: Это все комбинаторика: - [Размещения](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - [Перестановки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) - [Сочетания](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Был уже подобный [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533284/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-delphi/533403#533403). Там и теория, и код.

Comment: @slippyk, в данном случае указанный вами вопрос надо сделать дубликатом, так как он был задан почти на 4 года позже

Comment: @Grundy здесь автор не просит кода - а там именно код и нужен. И даже если учесть что тут код в ответах есть - здесь он на javascript, а там нужен Паскаль. Совсем не дубликаты.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну это как сказать, по теории сделать код вполне себе можно, так что в общем случае тот вопрос является дубликатом, просто с уточнением языка имплементации :)

Comment: @Grundy уточнение языка - достаточный повод чтобы не быть дубликатом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спорный вопрос, но данный вопрос дубликатом и не помечали :-)

Comment: а программа есть этого алгоритма?

Answer (score 32):

### Перестановки

*Перестановки* - это комбинации изначального массива, получаемые перестановкой элементов. Количество перестановок An = n! Алгоритм получения перестановки по номеру (1..n!) таков:

```js
var facts = [];
function fact(N){
    if(N==0 || N==1) return 1;
    if(facts[N]) return facts[N];
    facts[N] = N*fact(N-1);
    return facts[N];
}
function permutation(index, A){
    var n=A.length;
    var i=index+1;
    var res=[];
    for(var t=1;t<=n;t++){
        var f = fact(n-t);
        var k=Math.floor((i+f-1)/f);
        res.push(A.splice(k-1,1)[0]);
        i-=(k-1)*f;
    }
    if (A.length) res.push(A[0]);
    return res;
}

function log(){
  var msg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(" ");
  document.getElementById("log").value+="\n"+msg;
  console.log(arguments);
}
var M = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
for(var i=0;i<fact(M.length);i++){
    log(i,permutation(i,M.slice(0)).join(""));
}
```

```css
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%}
#log {width:100%;height:100%;border:0;padding:0;display:block}
```

```html
<textarea id="log"></textarea>
```

Смысл заключается в том, что мы на каждой итерации берем элемент из массива и убираем его, переходя к следующей итерации, имеем массив меньшей длины... и так продолжаем пока исходный массив не опустеет. При этом номер комбинации получается исходя из порядка вынимания элементов массива. Аналогичный подход используется в [алгоритме Фишера–Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0) для перемешивания массива, только там элемент, который будет выбран на каждой итерации берется случайным образом.

### Сочетания

*Сочетания* - это наборы определенной длины (k), составленные из множества определенной длины (n). Сочетания, в которых одни те же элементы поменены местами, считаются одним сочетанием, поэтому для удобства берутся те сочетания, элементы в которых упорядочены по возрастанию (в лексикографическом порядке). Количество сочетаний C(n,k) - читается как "Це из эн по ка", = n!/(k!(n-k)!), называются биномиальными коэффициентами. Алгоритм получения сочетания по номеру таков:

```js
var facts = [];

function fact(N) {
  if (N == 0 || N == 1) return 1;
  if (facts[N]) return facts[N];
  facts[N] = N * fact(N - 1);
  return facts[N];
}

function C(n, k) {
  return fact(n) / fact(k) / fact(n - k);
}

function combination(index, k, A) {
  var res = [0];
  var n = A.length;
  var s = 0;
  for (var t = 1; t <= k; t++) {
    var j = res[t - 1] + 1;
    while ((j < (n - k + t)) && ((s + C(n - j, k - t)) <= index)) {
      s += C(n - j, k - t);
      j++;
    }
    res.push(j);
  }
  res.splice(0, 1);
  return res;
}

function log() {
  var msg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(" ");
  document.getElementById("log").value += "\n" + msg;
  console.log(arguments);
}
var M = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
for (var i = 0; i < C(M.length, 3); i++) {
  log(i, combination(i, 3, M.slice(0)).join(""));
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%
}
#log {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<textarea id="log"></textarea>
```

Номер сочетания берется как сумма всех биномиальных коэффициентов для массивов уменьшающейся длины (на самом деле сформулировать кратко и притом понятно принцип нумерации сложно, ссылка на теорию будет ниже).

### Размещения

Сочетания и перестановки являются частными случаями *размещений*. 
Размещения - это сочетания, где важен порядок элементов. Или, другими словами, это перестановки сочетаний. Количество размещений A(n,k)=k!*C(n,k)=n!/(n-k)!.
Таким образом, чтоб получить размещение по номеру, делим общее количество размещений на цело на номер - получаем номер сочетания, и применяем к нему перестановку с номером как остаток от деления количества размещений на номер размещения.

### Размещения с повторениями

Отдельным вариантом комбинации является *размещение с повторением*. A'(n,k) = n^k. Т.е. все варианты массивов длины k, где на каждой позиции может быть любой элемент из множества размера n. Самый простой для понимания вариант - это A(10,k) -  все десятичные числа от 0 до 10^k-1. Или A(2,k) - все двоичные числа длины k.
Нумерация элементов натуральная, индекс комбинации соответствует десятичному аналогу числа в n-ричной системе счисления.

### См. также

Про нумерацию размещений и сочетаний можно почитать в статье "О нумерации перестановок и сочетаний для организации параллельных вычислений в задачах проектирования управляющих систем" (гуглится), алгоритмы приведены оттуда, ссылки в статье ведут на:

- Дейкстра Э. Дисциплина программирования.
- Липский В. Комбинаторика для программистов.

### Оптимизация

Поскольку расчеты ведутся с использованием факториалов, то для больших значений n,k скорее всего может потребоваться длинная арифметика. В то же время вполне возможно, что точное вычисление факториала не понадобится (надо проверять), и достаточно будет [формулы Стирлинга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0)... В приведенных алгоритмах функция факториала написана для простоты понимания.

### Обратная задача

Каждый из вариантов комбинаций может иметь обратную задачу - получение номера по комбинации. Имея представление о принципе нумерации обратная задача также решается. Например, для размещений с повторениями - это перевод n-ричной системы счисления в десятичную...

### Использование

Имея рассчитанные значения факториалов или вообще таблиц со всеми комбинациями определенного типа есть возможность получения случайной комбинации с использованием только одного вызова ГСЧ для получения комбинации.

Comment: Перебор элементов последовательностей в соответствии с последовательностью целых( обычно положительных ) чисел( от 0 до N ) один из самых простых и распространенных методов перебора последовательностей. Но тем не менее, один их самых эффективных.

Answer (score 6):

Не знаю, как это делается на php, но в теории можно применить следующий алгоритм:

Перебираем все числа от 0 (ни одного элемента) до (2^n) - 1 (все элементы), где n - длина масcива.

На каждом шаге перебора смотрим все биты числа, и если i-й бит равен единице, то i-й элемент будет входить в комбинацию.

Например, для трёх элементов:

- 0 - нет элементов
- 1 - (001) только 1й элемент
- 2 - (010) только 2й
- 3 - (011) 2й и 1й
- 4 - (100) только 3й
- 5 - (101) 1й и 3й
- 6 - (110) 1й и 2й
- 7 - (111) 1й, 2й, 3й

Answer (score 1):

1. Если элементы в линии должны быть уникальные, то например для N элементов число рекомбинаций = N x ... x 2 x 1.

Например, {"1", "2", "3"},  3 x 2 x 1 = 6 вариантов:
1-2-3
1-3-2
2-1-3
2-3-1
3-1-2
3-2-1

Теория выбора следующая: у первого из трех в линии может быть 3 разных варианта, у второго из трех в линии может быть только 2 оставшихся варианта, у третьего - только один единственный оставшийся.

2. Если элементы в линии могут повторяться, то число рекомбинаций = N в степени N.

Comment: может быть «в строке», а не «в линии»?

Answer (score -1):

```
    var facts = [];
function fact(N){
    if(N==0 || N==1) return 1;
    if(facts[N]) return facts[N];
    facts[N] = N*fact(N-1);
    return facts[N];
}
function permutation(index, A){
    var n=A.length;
    var i=index+1;
    var res=[];
    for(var t=1;t<=n;t++){
        var f = fact(n-t);
        var k=Math.floor((i+f-1)/f);
        res.push(A.splice(k-1,1)[0]);
        i-=(k-1)*f;
    }
    if (A.length) res.push(A[0]);
    return res;
}

function log(){
  var msg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(" ");
  document.getElementById("log").value+="\n"+msg;
  console.log(arguments);
}
var M = ["п","о","б","а","е","с","п","р","о","с","и","у"];
for(var i=0;i<fact(M.length);i++){
    log(i,permutation(i,M.slice(0)).join(""));
}
```

Comment: Вы прочитали вопрос? "не прошу кода, прошу теорию"

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.