# Генерация случайных сочетаний чисел

Tags: алгоритм, математика, typescript, комбинаторика

Имеется такая задача:
Есть несколько массивов возможных чисел. Таких массивов может быть 2, может быть 10, это не имеет значение. Также размер массивов может быть разным. Задача такова: надо случайным образом сгенерировать все не повторяющиеся комбинации чисел из этих массивов. Например,

```
const first : number[]= [1,2];
const second : number[] = [2,3,4];
const third : number[] = [3,4,5,6];
```

Задача такова: надо сгенерировать неповторяющиеся сочетания по одному числу из каждого массива.
Т.е.

```
(1,2,5), (2,3,4), (1,4,6), (2,3,5) и т.д.
```

Дополнительное и обязательное ограничение. При выборе числа с массива мы не должны знать, какие два остальных числа лежат внутри данного сочетания. Т.е. алгоритм должен быть stateless, т.е. не имеющим состояния. Т.е. например алгоритм сгенерировал два сочетания (1,2,5) и (2,3,4). И после генерации (2,3,4) алгоритм не должен проверять была ли такая комбинация до этого (он этого сделать и не может, поскольку не имеет предыдущего состояния).

Возможно ли решить такую задачу?

Comment: Вроде бы в boost есть функции генерации всех сочетаний, перестановок и размещений. Короче, такую задачу решить можно и она уже решена. Насчет stateless не очень понял, но думаю что тоже можно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, мне бы решение на TypeScript, если можно. Под отсутствием состояния (stateless) имеется в виду, что ты не знаешь, что было сгенерировано до текущей генерации. Вот есть текущая генерация множества чисел и она не должна зависеть от предыдущих генераций

Comment: Насчет TypeScript ничего не скажу так как я работаю с С/С++. Но думаю, что тоже давно сделано.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, сложность задачи в том, что в ней по сути нет никаких постоянных. Содержимое массивов чисел может быть разным, количество массивов тоже не ограничено, нет сохранения истории о предыдущих генерациях, поэтому мне и кажется, что задача из числа трудноватых

Comment: Сделать такое полностью stateless невозможно

Comment: Насколько я понял, для начала Вам надо создать один массив из неповторяющихся чисел. А потом сгенерировать все сочетания из его элементов (то есть из индексов этого массива).

Comment: @pepsicoca1, у меня уже есть на входе N массивов разной длины. Задача такая: должен быть что-то наподобие метода getNextVector(), который каким-то образом возвращает вектор, построенный из N индексов, где индекс - это порядковый номер в i-том массиве

Comment: @Zergatul [Сделать такое полностью stateless невозможно] Всегда можно сначала сгенерировать массив, а потом им пользоваться. Другое дело, что для большого количества элементов размер этого массива будет БОЛЬШОЙ. :-) С экспонентой-то шутки плохи, а с факториалом шутки еще хуже. :-)

Comment: А сочетание (2,2,3) у Вас может быть?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, да, конечно. Одинаковые или разные элементы - не имеет значения

Comment: @pepsicoca1 а индекс в массиве это не state?)

Comment: Вот статья по теме с примерами на С++. https://prog-cpp.ru/combinations/ Поищите, может и для TypeScript найдете. Или перепишите алгоритм с С++ на TypeScript. :-)

Comment: @Zergatul Индекс, конечно, state, но насколько я понял ТС хочет, чтобы ничто не хранилось МЕЖДУ вызовами. А внутри вызова хранится состояние может.

Comment: А вот человек ищет решение похожей проблемы на php. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482847/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Задача выглядит совершенно тривиальной. Просто создаем ровно столько вложенных циклов, сколько дано массивов: по первому, по второму и по третьему и т.д. массиву - и готов генератор сочетаний. Все. Никаких проверок на тему того, было ли уже такое сочетание, не нужно. Зачем?

Не совсем понятно требование stateless. Если вам нужно генерировать такие сочетания не сразу все, а по внешним запросам, при этом не сохраняя никакого state между запросами, то по предыдущему сочетанию всегда можно построить следующее просто выполнив поиск элементов в массивах и тем самым восстановив состояние итераций (подразумевая, что входные массивы не имеют повторяющихся элементов).

Разумеется, что-то придется давать на вход stateless-генератору, т.е. например предыдущее сочетание. Не может быть генератора детерминированной последовательности, который ничего не требует на вход и не хранит state.