# Комбинаторика SQL, C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Необходимо реализовать перебор всех возможных комбинаций точек выгрузки. Например, маршрут построен следующим образом:
1
2
3
4
5

Мне нужно получить все возможные комбинации

1
3
2
4
5

2
1
3
4
5

и тд.

Дайте пожалуйста толчок куда капнуть, как реализовать. Цель стоит в том, что бы перебрать все возможные варианты маршрута, и выбрать оптимальный исходя из суммы пробега по рейсу. ПО сделано в winforms, работает с БД, возможно делать этот перебор лучше в самом ПО или все таки на SQL ? Видел кучу костылей для c# с кучей `for`, мне этот вариант не нравится.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перебор комбинаций элементов массива в delphi](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533284/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-delphi)

Comment: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533284/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-delphi/) уже давал ответ, правда код на Delphi, но алгоритм там расписан понятно