# Генерация всех размещений символов строки

Tags: c, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Нужна функция генерации всех возможных комбинаций / перестановок символов строки.

Все возможные [размещения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) символов строки `abc`:
`abc
bac
bca
cab
cba
acb`

Решение в лоб — это сделать два цикла, копировать строку в массив результатов, и переставлять в нем литеру.

Будет ли рациональнее сделать двумерный массив указателей, и переставлять указатели на литеры? Или может есть более элегантный способ?

Comment: На самом деле, правильное решение зависит от полного описания задачи - максимальная длина входной строки, максимальное количество различных символов в ней, и, самое главное - так ли необходимо генерировать все перестановки, или важно знать только их количество?

Comment: @soon, перестановки необходимо генерировать, т.к. после их будем использовать.

Comment: Возьмите Кнута, "Искусство программирования", т.4А.

Comment: А язык именно си, или с++ позволителен?

Comment: Язык - только си.

Comment: Был подобный [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533284/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-delphi/533403#533403), правда про цифры, но разницы в алгоритме не будет.

Comment: Посмотрите как [next_permutation() можно реализовать](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)—не должно быть сложностей на С перевести swap() для указателей на символы в строке, и reverse() для строки, заданной указателями на концы.

Comment: Алгоритм, про который вам тут пытаются рассказать, периодически называя его "алгоримом Кнута" - это знаменитый Алгоритм Нарайаны: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тупо один в один переписанный алгоритм от Кнута...

```
int next_permutation(int * a, int n)
{
    int l, j = n-2;
    while (j >= 0 && a[j] >= a[j+1]) --j;
    if (j < 0) return 0;
    l = n-1;
    while (a[j] >= a[l]) --l;
    int tmp = a[j]; a[j] = a[l]; a[l] = tmp;
    ++j;
    l = n - 1;
    while(j < l)
    {
        tmp = a[j]; a[j] = a[l]; a[l] = tmp;
        ++j; --l;
    }
    return 1;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    do {
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
    } while(next_permutation(a,4));
}
```