# Массивы из разных слов. Метод подбора

Tags: массивы

У меня есть несколько слов, они должны составлять комбинацию из 15 слов.

Первое слово известно и оно будет стоять первым без изменений, мне надо сделать массив слов, где другие будут подставляться и создавать новую цепочку слов.

Например: **1 слово-кот…константа**,

2 слово-слон, бабочка, флаг,

3 слово-яхта, мяч, зеркало, песок и т.д.

Надо чтобы 1 слово присоединялось к другим вариантам.

**кот**-слон-яхта…

**кот**-слон-мяч

**кот**-слон-зеркало и т.д.

То есть все возможные варианты, которые могут появиться, если слова менять местами.

Начал в ручную писать все варианты, но это тихий ужас(

Comment: цепочка только из 15 слов, или могут быть и такие: `кот`, `кот-слон`, `кот-слон-мяч` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перебор комбинаций элементов массива в delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533284/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-delphi)

Comment: если только по 15, то вот [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533284/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-delphi/533403#533403), цифры - это индексы массива слов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать один из алгоритмов перебора перестановок элементов без повторений (`алгоритм перебора в лексикографическом порядке` или `перебор методом рекурсии`). Хорошее описание тут: [алгоритмы перебора](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8l6M.png). Можно сопоставить все слова числам, создать массив из чисел и применить к нему один из алгоритмов.

Пример решения на C++ (в данном примере к константному Cat добавляется 4 слова в разных перестановках):

```
// Генерация всех перестановок
// Основная идея алгоритма генерации всех перестановок заключается в следующем.
// В массиве длины n, содержащем перестановку, будем менять последний элемент с каждым, 
// после чего будем рекурсивно будем делать то же самое для массива длины n - 1 
// и затем возвращать переставленный элемент на старое место.Если достигнута длина массива n = 1, 
// то переставлять ничего не нужно, а следует выдавать содержимое всего массива - перестановки на экран.
// Такой алгоритм позволит сгенерировать все перестановки, что следует из словесного 
// рекурсивного определения : на последнем месте побывает каждый элемент, 
// содержащийся в рассматриваемом массиве, после чего к оставшейся части массива рекурсивно будет применен тот же алгоритм.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int n = 4;
int arr[n] = { 1,2,3,4 };
const string firstAnimal = "Cat";
string animals[n] = { "Monkey", "Dog", "Horse", "Bird" };
int cnt = 0;    // счетчик

void swap(int *arr, int a, int b);
void printArr(int *arr);
void Perm(int *arr, int k);

int main() {
    Perm(arr, n);
    return 0;
}

void Perm(int *arr, int k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        printArr(arr);
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            swap(arr, i, k - 1);
            Perm(arr, k - 1);
            swap(arr, i, k - 1);
        }
    }
}
void swap(int *arr, int a, int b) {
    int s = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = s;
}

void printArr(int *arr) {
    cnt++;
    cout << cnt << ".\t" << firstAnimal << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << animals[arr[i]-1] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Получается такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE:

Если нужно, чтобы подставлялись все слова из групп слов, то алгоритм простой по идее (честно говоря, я не уверен, что нет более оптимального решения). Взять все слова 1-й группы, добавить к каждому все слова второй группы и т.д., то есть столько групп, сколько циклов. Вот пример кода для 3-х групп слов:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string animal = "Кошка";
    string group1[] = { "молча", "громко", "ужасно" };
    string group2[] = { "лает", "мяукает", "говорит", "прыгает" };
    string group3[] = { "по утрам", "ночью" };

    for (int i = 0; i < _countof(group1); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < _countof(group2); j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < _countof(group3); k++)
                cout << animal << " " << group1[i] << " " << group2[j] << " " << group3[k] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вот что получается:

[image: все слова каждой группы для кошки]

Comment: Я совсем не знаю как это делать и какая оболочка нужна(

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример на с++, использует рекурсивный метод для перебора перестановок.

Comment: Круто! И выходит скрипт будет все возможные варианты комбинаций подбирать?
А где его запускать?

Comment: @НетуНет ну, алгоритм можно реализовать на разных языках, в зависимости от задачи, от того, где Вы планируете использовать его. Опишите подробнее немножко.

Comment: Просто дома запустить, для теста.
Но забыл ещё важный момент написать.
Каждое последующее слово, начиная со второго, включает в себя ещё слова....то есть просто в одну строчку нельзя все слова записать.

1 2 3 4 5
   2 3 4 5
      3    5
            5
то есть 1 должна сначала: 1 2 3 4 5 подбирать, потом 1, вторую 2, и снова первую 3 и т.д.

Comment: честно говоря, не очень понял. получается, у вас есть 15 групп со словами, и надо: `кошка`, `слово_из_группы1`, `слово_из_группы2` ... `слово_из_группы15` так?

Comment: Первое слово 1 и оно не меняется.
Второе слово: их может быть несколько, как и последующих, вплоть до 15-ого.
То есть надо отдельно забивать все слова в блок второго слова, все слова в блок третьего слова и т.д.

И программа должна будет из каждого блока брать слова и подставлять к первому.

Comment: Меня все смущает это "все слова". Видимо, все-таки все слова из одного блока в позицию этого блока в строке. В общем, если так, то я дополнил ответ, посмотрите, может подойдет. Запускать это в любой среде разработки с++, например, visual studio.

Comment: Максим это круто!
а на Винду 7 это среду отдельно как-то качать?

Comment: например, здесь https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/ . Если ответ Вам помог,  примите его как верный плз =)

Comment: Без проблем! А куда нажимать?

Comment: Там сверху, в начале ответа слева число и под ним галочка )

Comment: Максим, установил Visual Studio Core, но не понимаю куда код вставлять и как его запускать(

Comment: Честно говоря, тут я уже не подскажу. У меня только Visual Studio, не знаю что за Core честно говоря. Да и написать, как запустить приложение, нереально, это целую статью надо писать. Вам надо набрать в поиске "как создать консольное приложение в Visual Studio" и найти какой-нибудь пример, где Hello World программа простая пишется.

Comment: Максим, а вы в какой среде код делали и проверяли? Мне надо получается код из двух частей вставлять?

Comment: У меня Visual  Studio Community 2015, Вам по идее надо скачать то,что по ссылке выше внизу слева версия для windows, community. Там нужно создать проект "консольное приложение" и просто полностью вставить мой код вместо того, что будет по умолчанию, никаких двух частей.

Comment: Блин, у меня Винда 32х разрядная(

Comment: Установщик просит установить НетФрэймворк 4.6. версии, а она не ставится и Винда не обновляется.

Comment: Скачала Dev-C++, вставил код, F10 нажал, а мне ошибку выдает(
[Error] stdafx.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

Comment: Сложно что-то подсказать, но общий алгоритм действий должен быть такой: 1. создать новый проект (консольное приложение). 2. В нем сверху должны быть `#include <iostream>` и `#include <string>` - это необходимое. `stdafx` не нужно, можно его удалить. По идее все, должно так работать...

Comment: Блин не помогает( Удалил и теперь другая ошибка лезет.
Может в библиотеках проблемы?

Comment: То студия просит Винду 10, то Сервис Пак 1 для моей версии...я не знаю как этот код и чем запускать(

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в `_countof(group1)`, `_countof(group2)`, `_countof(group3)`. Эта функция считает,сколько элементов в массиве и из-за нее может проблемы. Попробуйте вместо них написать просто числа вот так: `for (int i = 0; i < ЗДЕСЬ_ЧИСЛО_СЛОВ; i++)`.  Остальной код должен работать везде, вот например онлайн компилятор c++: https://ideone.com/3RjGff

Comment: Я этот код запустил по ссылке и 17 ошибок вылезло.

Comment: Максим я запустил наконец-то! В Визуал Студио 2017.
Но как мне дополнить код, чтобы 15 групп слов стало?
То есть в консоли должно быть куча вариантов по 15 слов.

Comment: Получается 1, 8 и 9 слова у нас константы.
Либо 1 оставить как есть, и ещё добавить 14 групп...я так сделал, но скрипт считает только первое слово и три группы...я не пойму как дописать формулы(
Очень срочный вопрос! Максим очень жду помощи!

Comment: рад что получилось запустить =)  Вам нужно делать так: Делаете столько групп , сколько нужно, не обращая пока внимания на константы. Группы вида `string group2[] = { "лает", "мяукает", "говорит", "прыгает" };`. Далее: делаете также столько циклов, сколько групп вида `for (int j = 0; j < _countof(group2); j++)`. Это цикл. Нужно проследить, чтобы имена счетчиков в каждом цикле были уникальными  (int `j` = 0; `j` < _countof(group2); `j`++). Далее, после написания всех циклов, выводите строку: `cout << group1[i] << " " << group2[j] ... `

Comment: В этой финальной строке просто добавьте на позиции 1,8 и 9 нужные Вам слова. То есть будет что такое: `cout << "константа1 " << group1[i] << " " << group2[j] << " " << group3[k] << " " << group4[h] << "Константа8 " << "Константа9 " << group3[k] << endl;`

Comment: Если хотите, дайте Ваши группы, я напишу код и пришлю

Comment: Вы можете переписать код предыдущий? А то я наделаю(

Comment: Хотя группы не нужны, сейчас пришлю

Comment: Вроде готово. Проверил сейчас - там около 12800 комбинаций получается. В консоли все не будут видны ( Надо как-то думать, как их сохранить, если все нужны. Или выводить по частям. Скажите, куда текст кода скинуть

Comment: 12800 - это если по 2 слова в группе... Если больше - даже боюсь представить, сколько там получится =).