# "Сочетание" в комбинаторике, задача

Tags: комбинаторика

*Самостоятельно изучаю комбинаторику*

Есть задача о ряде цифр(8), четыре места в котором занимают нули. Нужно найти количество способов расставить нули.

Решается через формулу сочетаний без повторений. С=n!/k!(n-k)!, ответ 70.
Не могу понять:

1) В результате сочетания порядок не важен, есть "кучка". Но у нас он важен, ведь может быть ряд 00100111, а может 11110000.

2) Почему без повторений, ведь ноль повторяется?

Вроде сначала было понятно, а теперь ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы запутали себя нулями, перепутав физический смысл задачи и комбинаторный.

Множество в данной задаче - это индексы, на которых могут находиться нули: 1..8. И вы берете 4 разных индекса, получаете комбинацию.

Т.о. каждая комбинация характеризуется 4-мя индексами, на которых эти нули находятся. Количество таких комбинаций будет C из n по k (C из 8 по 4). Можете сами доказать это или поискать в сети.

Вот они эти комбинации, все 70 https://jsfiddle.net/04vvhvdt/1/

```
0 1234
1 1235
2 1236
3 1237
4 1238
5 1245
...
67 4578
68 4678
69 5678
```

Обратите внимание на то, как меняются индексы. Без повторений означает, что комбинация с индексами 1234 эквивалентна комбинации, например, 4321 и считается за одну комбинацию.

ЗЫ  Про различные перестановки довольно подробно (с кодом) писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154252/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/154353#154353).

Comment: Была ошибка в алгоритме, поправил.

Comment: Большое спасибо, начал понимать, странно что до меня не доходило.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос конечно имеет отдалённое отношение к программированию.

Формула C(n,k) - число способов выбрать k элементов из n, если порядок не имеет значения и выбранные элементы не повторяются.

В этой задаче мы выбираем *позиции* в которых будут 0. Понятно что на одной позиции может быть только одна цифра (0 или нет) и таким образом повторений не будет. Порядок выбора цифр нам не важен, так как на само число это не влияет.

Формула и ответ в вопросе верные.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю? Сочетание без повторений - это когда у нас имеется множество {a1,a2,...,an} и мы из него составляем сочетания длины k.  "Сочетание" само по себе подразумевает то, что мы берем из множества неважно как. Правда я не знаю, как еще можно брать из множества, потому что Размещение определил для себя как размещение из множества в ячейки - так проще понять.  Хотя, вроде как, Размещение, в отличие от сочетания - отличается порядком, но где он там я пока не понял, все равно перемешивание идет.  Ну так вот. Получается, у нас есть множество

Comment: цифр мощностью "n", из которого нам надо выбирать сочетания длины k=8 с четырьмя обязательными нулями.  1) Как избежать повторений при взятии из множества? Можно взять каждого из них как отдельную цифру, тогда не будет повторений. Иначе, получается, мы взяли ноль из множества больше одного раза.  2) Как "застолбить" эти нули? Какая гарантия того, что они каждый раз будут попадать в сочетания и там их будет именно четыре?  Простите за тупость.

Comment: перевожу на русский, вам надо сгенерировать эти числа?

Comment: Если можно, укажите в чем я неправ, главная задача у меня сейчас - разгрести бардак в переменных и сформировать в голове примерную картинку, логику. Например в вышеприведенной задаче, в качестве числителя дроби берется n, который по идее должен являться количеством вариантов, т.е. мощностью множества из которого делаем выборку. Но там его берут как 8!, то есть k! - факториал длины цепочки. Совсем запутался...

Comment: эм... я даже не знаю что ответить, N - число цифр, K - число 0.