# Разбиение масива на блоки

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, олимпиада

> Дан одномерный массив положительных чисел. Нужно разбить этот массив
>   на определённое кол-во блоков так, чтобы разница между суммами
>   соседних блоков была минимальной. Порядок следования элементов массива
>   изменять нельзя.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как решать такие задачи?

Пример: `50,60,90,15,70,20` разбить на 3 блока.

Ответ: `|50,60| |90| |15,70,20|`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Чтобы получить три блока необходимо расставить два разделителя (на месте запятых). Это сочетания, которых будет C(5,2)=5!/(2!(5-2)!)=10 штук.
2. Перебираете их все:

   ```
   1,2
   1,3
   1,4
   1,5
   2,3
   2,4
   2,5
   3,4
   3,5
   4,5
   ```
3. Для каждой комбинации формируете набор блоков, например:

   ```
   2,4 => 50,60 | 90,15 | 70,20
   ...
   3,4 => 50,60,90 | 15 | 70,20
   ```
4. Для каждой комбинации получаете разности (по модулю):

   ```
   2,4 => 50,60 | 90,15 | 70,20 => 110-105 , 105-90 => 5,15
   ```
5. Запоминаете наилучшую комбинацию (или несколько лучших комбинаций), проверяя сумму разностей, она должна быть минимальной.

**UPD**
Вы можете оценить время выполнения одной итерации и прикинуть сколько будет выполняться 4,5млрд итераций (при 100к элементов в массиве). В рамках олимпиады, конечно, такого задания не будет, но есть варианты распараллеливать процесс. 
Сочетания можно пронумеровать ([тут писал про нумерацию комбинаций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154252/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/154353#154353), там же есть название статьи где решают такую задачу), разбить внешний цикл на несколько потоков...

При большом количестве элементов, полный перебор будет неоптимальным, понятное дело. Можно рассмотреть альтернативу. Разбить массив на три (изначально равные) части и двигать разделители в нужных направлениях в зависимости от сумм. Т.е. начинаем перебирать сочетания от 2,4 в разные стороны, проверяя окрестности:

```
2,4 => 1,4 или 2,5 или 2,3 или 3,4
```

В результате получим или нет более оптимальное сочетание (или несколько).

Другой вариант выбора начального сочетания: посчитать сумму всех элементов массива, поделить на три, и в цикле по порядку следования накапливать сумму до первой трети, потом до второй. Получим начальное сочетание, относительно которого также проверить окрестности.

3-5 пункты остаются те же.

Comment: А если в массиве 100 000 элементов? @Yura Ivanov

Comment: @VladslavRublevskii обновил ответ