# как инициализировать 5-ти мерный массив?

Tags: java, массивы

Привет!
Есть простой массив `Object[] arr = new int[50]` заполненный некими значениями, также есть другой массив `Object[][][][][] fiveDArr`, правда он 5-ти мерный, нужно скопировать все значения из первого в 5-ти мерный массив так чтобы было типа:`fiveDArr[arr][arr][arr][arr][arr]`
Пробовал такое:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, fiveDArr[i][j][k][n][m], 0, 50);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

к сожалению словил NullPointerException.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться - зачем это нужно?

Comment: хороший вопрос, хочу реализовать перебор всех возможных сочетаний из 50 ти значений, поэтому 5ти мерный массив. а перебор нужно делать именно по 5 уникальных объекта.

Comment: 5 раз делать одно и тоже... напишите метод, принимайте в аргументах 2 массива - исходный и целевой, а также инт , который "объяснит", куда именно копировать. + нет повторений кода, + настраиваешь метод единожды, т.е. только для одного копирования, а работает он сколько угодно, т.е. проще отладить и отловить баги. правда суть вопроса бредовая какая-то, подумайте над архитектурой приложения. похоже, что вы пишите что-то для очень узконаправленного условия, подумайте о масштабировании, о том, что через какое-то время у вас,например,не 5 массивов на входе будет. может так получится что-то изменить

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович тут автору нужны не куча одинаковых массивов, а куча разных.

Comment: автору нужно скопировать несколько одномерных массивов в один многомерный, насколько я понял. не вижу препятствий для написания указаноннго выше метода...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем вам это фиг знает, но пусть будет так:

```
Object[] objArr = new Object[50]//инициализированный где-то снаружи массив

int incremetObjArr = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                    fiveDArr[i][j][k][n][m] = objArr[incremetObjArr++];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но судя по всему ваш 5 мерный массив вмещает 2 в 5 степени т.е 32 элемента, а вам надо 50.

---

Задача оказалась сложнее и лежит в области комбинаторики (все возможно уникальные последовательности объектов из одного массива).

Нашел очень хороший ответ с формулами, примерами и кодом тут рядом [комбинаторика на ru.SO.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/154353/246094). Там все подробно описано, повторять тут теорию не буду. Если смогу - дополню кодом, но позже.

---

Поправьте если не прав, но судя по посту сверху все возможные комбинации 50 объектов == факториалу от 50 == `30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000`

т.е. должно быть 50 вложенных циклов, а не 5. Моему компьютеру удалось уместить 1,5 млн объектов на 256 мб RAM, а число сверху я даже произнести не могу, не то чтобы представить сколько памяти надо =)

---

Поэкспериментировал на массиве в 5 элементов (5 вложенных циклов). Только собирал не массивы, а строки с указанием индекса элемента и складывал их в `Set`, чтобы точно исключить повторы. Пришел пока к единственному решению (для человека незнакомого с комбинаторикой напрочь).

По сути в решении используются 5 система счисления, где каждая цифра будет обозначать номер элемента в исходном массиве.

```
    int arraySize = 5;
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (int y = 0; y <arraySize ; y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {
            if (y == x) continue; // такие if  в начале каждого цикла, чтобы исключить повторы цифр внутри последовательности

            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                if (x == i || y == i) continue;

                for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
                    if (i == j || x == j || y == j) continue;

                    for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++) {
                        if (j == k || i == k || x == k || y == k) continue;

                        String e = "" + x + i + j + k; 
                        set.add(e);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Полностью этот код с выводом [по ссылке Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/knZL6f).

Comment: так точно мне надо грубо говоря мне в каждом ijk по 50 значений. спасибо ваш ответ натолкнул на хорошую мысль)

Comment: @ХамидиллоМамытов рад, что натолкнул, потому что "мне надо грубо говоря мне в каждом ijk по 50 значений" понять немного сложновато =)

Comment: я думаю Вы поняли, fiveDArr[arr[50]][arr[50]][arr[50]][arr[50]][arr[50]] как то так)

Comment: я сейчас понял, что циклы не дадут нужный результат( мне надо поочередно заполнять. нужно что то вроде рекурсии

Comment: @ХамидиллоМамытов понял, опять же вопрос с какой целью это нужно. Но тут зависит от того нужен ли вам оптимальный алгоритм(точный и быстрый) или нужен результат наименьшим кодом(точный, но может быть очень долгим)?

Comment: Учтите, что 50 в пятой степени, это 312.5 миллионов значений в массиве. Зачем столько может быть нужно - представить сложно, но что бы это не было - оно повесит вам систему.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр я тоже поначалу так подумал, но новых объектов не создается, только ссылки на них копируются, так что куча не страдает. А вот насчет кучи ссылок не уверен, если честно не совсем понимаю как это работает (300 млн ссылок на 50 объектов)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ=) действительно если не знать обходных путей.. решил задачку, как оказалось все намного проще! и да видимо я перестарался с вопросом но вы вроде меня поняли "Задача оказалась сложнее и лежит в области комбинаторики (все возможно уникальные последовательности объектов из одного массива)."(объясняю я плохо) я отвечу на свой вопрос если интересно посмотрите :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void sortOutAllPossibleDealerHands() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFCARDS - 4; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < NUMBEROFCARDS - 3; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < NUMBEROFCARDS - 2; k++) {
                for (int n = k + 1; n < NUMBEROFCARDS - 1; n++) {
                    for (int m = n + 1; m < NUMBEROFCARDS; m++) {
                       arrayListToSort.add(cardsToArray[i]);
                       arrayListToSort.add(cardsToArray[j]);
                       arrayListToSort.add(cardsToArray[k]);
                       arrayListToSort.add(cardsToArray[n]);
                       arrayListToSort.add(cardsToArray[m]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот конкретно данный код перебирет все значения в массиве и даст все возможные уникальные значения. правда, я надеюсь что это так! но теперь у меня проблемы с производительностью(