# Все варианты двумерного массива из чисел

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Есть набор чисел `1 2 3 4`. нужно составить все возможные варианты двумерного массива

```php
    [
      [ 1, 2 ]
      [ 3, 4 ]
    ]
    
    
    
    [
      [ 1, 2 ]
      [ 4, 3 ]
    ]
    
    
    [
      [ 1, 3 ]
      [ 2, 4 ]
    ]
```

В результате должно получиться 4! = 24 массива на выходе. Подскажите алгоритм, пожалуйста

Comment: Есть, например, такой алгоритм для генерации всех возможных комбинаций: [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm). С помощью него можно составить все комбинации для одномерного массива `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, а потом уже одномерный массив представить в виде матрицы.

Comment: да. то что нужно. спасибо

Answer (score 5):

[Все возможные комбинации одномерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154252/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)
Если смотреть Вашу формулировку перестановки двумерного массива, то можно просто использовать перестановку и разделять числа по середине. Вообще Вы не учли вариант [[1], [2, 3, 4]] где по сути ещë 24 варинта, а может быть и наоборот, плюс варианты где массив пустой и в итоге с перестановкой массива всего 24+24+24+24+24 = 120 вариантов. Думаю, что перестановкой) но если только так, как Вы хотите, то ознакомьтесь со ссылкой. И просто разделяйте дополнительно массив на пополам)